# Twilio 11200 errors in sms status callback

Tags: node.js, sms, twilio

We are using node.js to send SMS to customers, and recently added the status callback to log sent and delivered statuses.  We are also now seeing a ton of 11200 errors in our Twilio logs on calls that apparently were successful.  Looking at the debugger, I see this in the response body:

> Twilio was unable to fetch content from:
>   https://api.mycompany.com:443/api/1.0/sms/response Error: Error
>   reading response: Response does not contain content type

and the message text has:

> Msg   "Request to StatusCallback URL was unsuccessful."
>   httpResponse  "502"

On our side, the handler for /api/1.0/sms/response takes the MessageSid sent with the response, matches it to one in the database, then looks at the MessageStatus.  For "sent" it logs the current time in a sent field and saves it back to the database, likewise for delivered.  At the end, it just does a res.end() as shown in the [node.js example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-confirm-delivery-in-node-js#getting-status-events-for-twiml-generated-messages).

Here's the code:

```
app.post('/api/1.0/sms/response', function(req, res) {
    var post_id = req.body.MessageSid || "";
    var status = req.body.MessageStatus || "";
    var item = Item.create(globals);

    if (post_id === "") {
        globals.logger.error(moduleName, "POST sms/response", "Missing MessageSid: " + JSON.stringify(req.body), true);
        res.end();
        return;
    }

    item.loadFromPostId(post_id).then(function() {
        if (status.toLowerCase() === "sent") {
            item.sent = new Date();
        }
        else if (status.toLowerCase() === "delivered") {
            item.delivered = new Date();
        }

        item.save().then(function() {
           res.end();
        });

    });
});
```

Looking at a couple of the errors, they are when Twilio is trying to send a "delivered" status to us.  Checking our database for the MessageSids from these errors, the matching item has a timestamp in the "delivered" column, so it made it all the way through the code to the save.

We also have nothing but 200 responses in our nginx log (which we are using in front of node) for this endpoint, no upstream timeouts and no 502s.  So I don't know where this error is coming from, or how to get rid of it.

And yes, we should be handling undelivered, etc., but this was just a quick pass at getting some responses in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should respond with HTTP status code 204:

```
res.status(204).end();
```

The 204 status is still a success, like 200, but specifically means you are not sending any content back (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).
Note that the following also works, and doesn't need the end():

```
res.sendStatus(204);
```

Comment: Finally got back to this, and this is actually the better solution, so changing the answer.  If you respond with status 200, you will get a bill for another text being sent that corresponds to the "OK" status of 200.  If you send a 204, you do not get that extra charge.

Comment: Apologies, didn't realise you were getting that with the 200 response. I have made a new PR to correct this in the example again: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/api-snippets/pull/738.

Comment: Aagh, I didn't re-read my own question.  I'll stick with the 204 on the status callback as the best choice, but the extra charge does not come there, but on an incoming sms webhook.  That's the one where a 200 response with no body actually sends "OK" back to the person who sent the text, incurring a charge, but 204 does not.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First up, you have nothing to worry about here. As you say, you are receiving the callbacks and doing what you need to. You probably want to stop the debugger icon flashing at you in your Twilio console though.

From what I can see, this is a small oversight in the case of the Node.js example that you linked to.

Just calling `res.end()` closes the stream. It appears that if nothing else has been set, this means the response will get a status code of 200 and no body. While Twilio doesn't expect a response to callbacks like this, it seems it still wants to know something happened.

The error message says that the response didn't have a content type. You can remedy this by setting a content type on the response by calling `res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')` before you call `res.end()` and that seems to please the Twilio HTTP client.

Alternatively, you can use the express response method [`sendStatus`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus) to set the status and content type of the response in one call. Just call `res.sendStatus(200)` and the response will be set to `text/plain`, the status will be 200 and there will be a body of "OK". The Twilio HTTP client will happily accept all of that.

I recommend you change your calls to `res.end()` to `res.sendStatus(200)` and I'm going to go fix that in the Node.js example too.

Comment: Thanks - patched code this morning - we've sent a half dozen so far, and there have been no 11200s, which is pretty conclusive, since 100% had warnings before the patch.